# Can I make grapes honey from grape juice only

Tags: honey, grapes

Following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8MRDzV41QI), we can see how to make grapes honey from grapes. Is there also a way to make grapes honey from 100% grape juice (instead of the whole grapes)? As can be seen in the video the process is based on several times of boiling while stirring the grapes.

Comment: Avi, could you please describe the process *in your post* and *in English*. The community tends to frown upon questions where they need to watch a video to understand what the asker is talking about. And when the majority of users can’t even understand the description there, it’s really not enough information to work with. Please [edit] your post accordingly, thanks!

Comment: I am surprised - I see no traces of skins or seeds in the liquid in the metal bowl? I doubt that they would dissolve so completely. Is there a step that we are missing? And: Is the mix pure grapes, or is there some form of sugar added? With skins, I would expect the result to be some kind of jam, as the skins release pectin during boiling, that causes gelling of the product when it cools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of food is known in English as a "treacle", and it can be made from a variety of fruit, not just grapes.

You can surely make it from pure grape juice. You don't need to add sugar, the whole point of treacle is to concentrate the sugar of the grapes to use it as a sweetener on its own. Adding sugar would be redundant.

You don't need to make it with whole grapes, in fact it is better to use juice only. The fewer dry mass you have, the less burnt off-tastes you will get. Also, some parts of the fruit will never dissolve fully, as Stephie mentioned, so with whole fruit, you normally have to sieve it. It is easier to start with the juice already, then you only have to boil out the major part of the liquid. The reasons that it is traditionally done with whole fruit is that 1) it is less effort to boil, then sieve, than to press juice (sieving all the while) then boil, and 2) you will get more treacle per kg of grapes if you start with the whole fruit (although it will be less refined).

Comment: Thanks a lot @rumtscho! I wondered what is the time and the required temperature for extracting the grape's treacle from their juice?

Comment: @Avi there is no one special combination of time and temperature. You set it at a temperature at which you can manage it without burning, and then cook it until it is ready.